# Why I am not able to receive sms using AT commands?

Tags: sms, command, modem, gsm, at-command

I want to send / receive sms using AT commands from my computer to my mobile phone. I connected my phone to my computer using a USB port. My computer detects the modem and I am able to send sms from the computer to mobile phone. However, I am not able to receive sms in my computer..

I am presenting a sample of what I get from AT editor

AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0
Error

What can I do to send this prob and why am I getting this Error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every phone has different capabilities so you should check which values for each parameter are valid for your phone by sending it a

> AT+CNMI=?

For example my phone doesn't support your example because mode 1 is not supported. For the full syntax of +CNMI you can consult the AT Manual of your manufacturer or the ETSI standard or read this brief tutorial http://www.cellular.co.za/at_etsi.htm

AT+CNMI is used anyway just to get a notification when a SMS arrives, in order to read the content of the stored SMS you have to use AT+CMGL= or AT+CMGR=.

Briefly:
AT+CMGF=1 ;sets the text mode

AT+CMGL=? ;tells you which memories are available

AT+CSCS=? ;tells you which character sets are available

AT+CSCS="8859-1" ;sets Latin1 as the charset so that you can see eventually accented letters

AT+CMGL="ALL" ;prints every text message you have stored in your phone

Comment: I tried these commands but I got "ERROR" in return.. Does that mean my mob does n't support these commands ? BTW I am using Nokia x300 ..Can u suggeest any  phone that supports these commands ?

Comment: Almost any GSM/CDMA phone has this basic commands. You can check if the phone support the command by issuing a AT+CLAC and see if they're in the list. Also, pay attention to the double quotes. The commands don't end with ";" it's just a separator between the command and my comment

Comment: `AT+CSCS="UTF-8"` usually is a much better choice than 8859-1.

Comment: @hlovdal In first place my old phone doesn't support it. Plus the texts I receive are correctly interpreted only with iso-8859-1. I'm not saying that you're wrong, on the contrary! It's better to choose utf-8 when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the phones returns Error when some special AT command sent to them and +CNMI is one of that command. It will return error also when send AT+CNMI=?.

So forget Phones buy a GSM Modem based on RS232 or USB and then try it again.

Comment: Experienced the same with Nokia 6120. Using a modem would be the best option.