# Reading SMS Through HSDPA Modem with At Commands

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem

I am trying to Read SMS through HSDPA Modem. I Tried

1. AT+CMGR=1
2. AT+CMGR=123
3. AT+CMGR="ALL'
4. AT+CMGR="REC ALL"
5. AT+CMGL="ALL"

Commands but No Sucess. Is Any problem with serialport configuration or something else Any other possible solution please help me

1. Baud Rate:9600
2. Data bits:8
3. Parity:None
4. Stop bit:1

Comment: HSPDA is distinct from SMS. What does your modem's documentation say?

Comment: I got it From BSNL India they Did't provide any Documentation

Comment: Have you seen this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235030/why-i-am-not-able-to-receive-sms-using-at-commands?rq=1

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "no success"? Could you post the complete command and response serial communication?

Comment: Would be useful to see what you sent and received from the serial connection so that we can help you here. Do any AT commands work? Have you tried to send just AT to see if you get and OK back?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have connected your terminal emulator to your modem (typically /dev/ttyUSB0 on Linux), try `AT`. If you get an `OK` or `ERROR` that means you have no problem with serial port configuration because the modem is responding to you. If you get *nothing* (ei, no reply from the modem), then you probably have a serial connection or modem hardware issue. Personnaly I'm using `miniterm.py` (on Linux) and the configuration is

```
maurice@mickey> sudo miniterm.py -e /dev/ttyUSB0`
--- Miniterm on /dev/ttyUSB0: 9600,8,N,1 ---
```

Just as yours.

Regarding reading the SMSes, `at+cmgl=?` should reply either `ERROR` or a list of statuses. If you get `ERROR`, this means your modem doesn't accept SMS. Otherwise you should get something like `+cmgl: ("REC UNREAD","REC READ","STO UNSENT","STO SENT","ALL")`

Now, if you issue `at+cmgr`, the answer should look like

```
+CMGL: 8,"REC UNREAD","+XXXXXXXXXXXX",,"16/02/19,19:52:07+12"
Test 1
+CMGL: 9,"REC UNREAD","+XXXXXXXXXXXX",,"16/02/19,19:52:16+12"
Test 2
```

where +XXXXXXXXXXXX is the sender MSISDN and "*Test 1*" is the message sent in the SMS (its content). Again, if you get `ERROR`, that means your modem doesn't accept SMSes. If you have sent some SMSes but the list is empty, maybe SMS are blocked on the HLR for this specific SIM.

To read the 8th SMS, issue `at+cmgr=8` and you should get

```
+CMGR: "REC READ","+XXXXXXXXXXXX",,"16/02/19,19:52:07+12"
Test 1

OK
```

Comment: I type this `sudo miniterm.py -e /dev/ttyUSB0` and works. but it always reply OK not stopping. And when I type `at+` it says command not support